# Why doesn't Captain Holt have his rainbow flag in the New Girl crossover

Tags: brooklyn-nine-nine, new-girl

Captain Holt is openly gay in Brooklyn 99 and has a rainbow flag on his desk:
[image]

In 4th episode in season 6 of New Girl "homecoming", we see the main part of the crossover episode with Brooklyn nine-nine.

Jess has an interview with Captain Holt in his office, and his rainbow flag is not evident, nor are other rainbow references visible:

Is this likely to be deliberate, or just the way cameras/set rigging happened to capture it?

Comment: Is there any reason for Holt to have it always in his office?I think in many episodes of Brooklyn nine-nine we won't see it either. Being gay doesn't mean having a rainbow flag everywhere you go

Comment: Have you actually watched the show? He doesn't take it with him, he places it on his desk in a mug.. It would only not be there if it was deliberately removed... The fact it wasn't there in the New Girl episode was therefore jarring.

Comment: Is this the whole scene? Other than the lamp, all the desk items are different. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kIkMIxJYaU

Comment: @OrangeDog perhaps they redressed the whole set - I suppose I assumed it was left ready to go between episodes, etc.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I'm not going to look for a shot of it from the same series to compare. There aren't any in the crossover episode itself (Night Shift). If it was a completely separate crew (you can check the credits) then the props/production team probably did re-dress how they wanted it.

Comment: @Vishwa this isn't a question on LGBT life it's a question about a TV show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the flag is not always there:

Googling for "Captain Holt desk" I've found a few pictures where the flag was missing from its usual spot on the desk:

[image]

But that doesn't mean that there is no rainbow: in the picture above, you can see the rainbow on the colourful stone behind the name plate.

Here, look at the folders behind Holt:

[image]

I couldn't find a picture of the desk from the crossover episode, but it is quite possible that the rainbow was still there, although in a more subtle way than the flag in the cup.

Comment: I believe it varies over time - you're right there are a lot more LGBT/pride references in more or less overt placings. I found one or two more re-visiting this question myself.